# Multiple sheets and columns in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets, one named "Raw Data", and one named "Oakland Department Data".

In a column in ODD, I'm trying to pull the number from a column in Raw Data. The number has to match several columns in Raw. It has to be from "Oakland(column a), It has to be a specific department (col b, ex "cardiology"), and it then has to take the value belonging to those two columns, from a third column, and bring over to the column in department data.

I've tried

```
=INDEX('Raw Data'!D:D,MATCH('Raw Data'!A:A,ʺ=Oaklandʺ,'Raw Data'!B:B,ʺBMOB Procedure Suite - Adultʺ, 0))
```

and

```
=INDEX('Raw Data'!D:D, MATCH('Raw Data'!A:A,(=ʺOaklandʺ), 'Raw Data'!B:B, (=ʺCardiology/Treadmill 3 - Adultʺ)))</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=INDEX('Raw Data'!D:D,MATCH("Oakland" & "BMOB Procedure Suite - Adult",'Raw Data'!A:A&'Raw Data'!B:B,0))
```

and enter it is an array formula. (Press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter` when exiting cell edit mode).